# Why isn't my Socket closing on server side?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to make a simple text editor which can be shared accross multiple terminals at the same time. I have a `Server` waiting for new users, when a user enters the shared editor it just starts waiting for input characters.

```
public class Server {
    public static final int PORT = 8080; 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("A new user entered the sever");
            new Thread(() -> serve(socket)).start();
        }
    }

    private static void serve(Socket socket) {
        try {
            while (!socket.isClosed() && !socket.isInputShutdown()) {
                System.out.println("hey " + socket.isClosed() + " " + socket.isInputShutdown());
                System.out.print(new String(SocketUtil.receiveBytes(socket,1)));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When a user closes the editor, the socket is closed on client side. However, the socket on the server side does not get closed and the server starts looping infinitly in the "wait for input" loop.

The `Client` is a singleton containing the following methods, called at the openning and closing of the editor.

```
public static void init() {
        try {
            if (socket == null) socket = new Socket(HOST,Server.PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            kill();
            throw new Error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void kill() {
        Check.notNull(socket);
        try {
            SocketUtil.terminateCommunication(socket);
            System.out.println(socket.isClosed());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Finally, here are utilitary methods (in `SocketUtil`) used in both classes :

```
public static void terminateCommunication(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    socket.shutdownInput();
    socket.shutdownOutput();
    socket.close();
}

public static char[] receiveBytes(Socket socket, int nBytes) throws IOException {
    char[]            bytes = new char[nBytes];
    InputStreamReader isr   = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    isr.read(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

Any idea of why the socket on server side is not closed after the `Client` gets killed ?

Comment: On an unrelated note: a) better not use confusing names such as `char[] bytes` - should be `char[] chars` instead; b) it's not a good idea to write multiple operators on a single line, like `if (socket == null) socket = ...` - this makes the code harder to read and debug (because debuggers usually run the code line-by-line).

Comment: @Brian, it's not a duplicate, although these questions are related. This question is mostly about how `isClosed()` and `isInputShutdown()` work, while the other one doesn't even mention these.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: Duplicate removed, though there's a lot of duplicate information there. Seemed like attaching the output buffer to the socket and closing the buffer, then waiting for the socket to close on it's own is the best path.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Yes, before some refactoring it was a byte arrya I must have forgotten to change the name. About the one-liner, many people would agree with you and maybe even I, but I got used to one-liners in Scala. In this case I don't think it hurts that much

Comment: @Dici, no, not much, just a little bit. By the way, singletons are generally considered evil, so that line maybe should go away along with the singleton, as this is certainly not a typical use case for the Singleton Pattern (if there's one).

Comment: @SergeyTachenov I just wanted that someone out of the `Client` and `Server`'s package can only open a single communication with the server

Comment: @Dici, you should put that limitation somewhere else. Just make the user interface that can't possibly initiate multiple connections (although somebody can still launch two instances of your application, so if you want to accept only one connection per host, you better do it in the server). To name just one reason why using a Singleton in this case is wrong: what if someone wants to use your class to initiate multiple connections to _different_ servers? The code should be reusable and as useful as possible.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov yeah, I agree. Should I use the `InnetAddress` of the socket to implement the limitation on the server ? With a set, I guess.

Comment: @Dici, probably yes, if one connection per remote host is what you want. Of course, it will cause problems if multiple clients are behind a NAT with the same address, but that's beyond the scope of this question, and we got side-tracked enough already, I believe.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov haha you're right, thank you for all the advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear from the Javadoc, but `isClosed()` only returns `true` when you have explicitly called `close()` on the socket (see the sources to confirm that). You should check for exceptions *and* the return value of `read()` instead. If you read `-1` or catch an `IOException` while trying to read (or write, for that matter), it essentially means that the other side has closed the connection, so you should close your socket as well (better to it in a `finally` block) and you're done with that particular connection. You don't check for `-1` in `receiveBytes()`, but you really should. Perhaps throw a `EOFException()` if you want to merge these two possibility into one, so that the code up the stack (in `serve()`) doesn't have to figure out what exactly happened:

```
public static char[] receiveBytes(Socket socket, int nBytes) throws IOException {
    char[]            bytes = new char[nBytes];
    InputStreamReader isr   = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    if (isr.read(bytes) == -1)
        throw new EOFException();
    return bytes;
}
```

One exception from the `IOException` rule (sorry for the pun) is the `SocketTimeoutException`. If you get this, the connection is still alive, and you may just as well retry your `read()`. But I believe that in order to get these, you must call `Socket.setSoTimeout()` somewhere, and if you haven't, then you probably shouldn't worry about `SocketTimeoutException`.

You should also note that `read()` may sometimes return partial reads (that is, less than `bytes.length`). If it's important that `receiveBytes()` reads exactly `nBytes` (which probably is, since you never return the number of actual characters read), then you should call it in a loop, like this:

```
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < bytes.length) {
        int l;
        if ((l = isr.read(bytes, pos, bytes.length - pos)) == -1) {
            throw new EOFException();
        }
        pos += l;
    }
```

I know this is cumbersome, which is exactly why many developers create utility methods like your `receiveBytes()`.

Comment: I don't know if I can rely on a timeout here, because the user could simply be idle, or thinking about what he is going to write... He can send messages to the server and leave the shared editor at any time.

Comment: @Dici, no, what I meant to say was, if you get a SocketTimeoutException, then the connection is still alive, and you may call `read()` again. But if you get any other IOException, it is closed by the other side. Should I edit my answer to make it clearer somehow? I'll try.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Like I said on the other answer, I will try to apply your advices when I will be on my computer

Comment: You're right, I should not have skipped the `-1` check. I updated the method to throw an exception if the number of chars read is not the one expected (in parameter)

Comment: @Dici, no, that's wrong. You can get partial reads sometimes. You should only throw exceptions when getting `-1`. See my another edit.

Comment: In which case would I receive less than `nBytes` without the end of the "file" to be reached ?

Comment: @Dici, for example, when the network splits up a message so that a part of your message belongs to one TCP packet, and a part to another. With a bit of bad luck, you may just read one part, with another one coming in within a few milliseconds. If you used UDP, that wouldn't be a problem, though, 'cause it's all-or-nothing, but then you could miss entire messages.

Comment: Seems that I have a lot to learn about sockets and protocols... thanks a lot !

Comment: @Dici, learning is always a good idea, but in this case it doesn't even have anything to do with sockets. It's the specifications of the `Reader` and `InputStream` interfaces that clearly indicate that you get `-1` on EOF, and you may get less data than you asked for, so you should always be prepared for that and use a loop. Note how it's different from `write()` that always writes everything unless it throws an exception. The rarely used `DataInput` interface has `readFully()` methods that address the `read()` problem, but alas nothing like that in the regular readers or streams.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to detect that the client has closed its connection is by checking the reception of 0 bytes.

```
 System.out.print(new String(SocketUtil.receiveBytes(socket,1)));
```

just check if the string is empty should do the trick.
Note that I am not that familiar with java, but I do know socket programming. 
Receiving 0 bytes, checking for that, and closing the socket if you do is a good solution.

You can use exception handling too, but you'll detect that the peer closed it socket an iteration later. Receiving 0 bytes is not really an error condition it is just a signal from the peer that he has closed its end of the socket and won't send anymore data. If you ignore this, and keep using the socket, you'll receive an exception in the next iteration because there is nothing to receive anymore.

Comment: I'm gonna try this, but the strange thing is I don't get an exception on server side, `receiveBytes` is called infinitly. This might indeed mean that I'm receiving 0 bytes, because when I print it, it is empty. I will be able to test it in the next hour, I will tell you

Comment: @Dici, oops, I forgot about another possibility. No, you shouldn't ever receive 0 bytes according to the `InputStream` Javadoc, but you can get `-1` that indicates EOF, which in this case would mean that the socket is closed. See my edited answer.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov I casted the returned value to an `int`, I get `0`, which is apparently the `NUL` character. So fine, it makes sense to make it my exit condition but... why ? I called `shutdownOutput`, I would expect it to shut it on both sides

Comment: @Dici, what `isr.read(bytes)` returns 0? Or does it put zero into `bytes`? That's two different things. It returns the number of character read, but it blocks until some input is available, so I can only imagine it returning 0 if it partially reads a multi-byte character. On EOF it should return `-1`, and you should have no need to cast it to `int` because it's `int` already.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Nope, 0 was the value of the character in the returned array, which makes sense, it is like the `null` value of chars

Comment: @Dici, it does shut down on both sides, but the other side only detects it via an I/O operation, which is usually `read()`. That actually makes sense, because how would a `Socket` know about connection being closed without making any underlying I/O calls. What is misleading here, is how the methods `isClosed()` and such totally ignore the actual connection status even after it is detected by `read()`. Plus vague docs. No wonder one gets confused.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov but `read` **was**called even after the socket being closed, and instead of waiting it returned -1 immediately. Nevermind, it works now :p Thanks

Comment: @Dici, right. But `isClosed()` still returned `false`, even after that, right? Makes no sense, and isn't clear from the docs either. That's what I'm talking about.